# How to take a photo like this where the small object appears big and vice versa?

Tags: special-effects

[image]

So I was wondering is the girl standing very far back or something else...?

Answer (score 1):

You can't *take* a photo like this unless you know someone who is very good at creating artificial plants that look very lifelike but are hundreds of time larger than the plants they are emulating. What you can do is *create* an image like this using elements from two or more different photos and combining them in a way that makes it look like a single exposure.

There is a technique called *[forced perspective](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/10098/15871)* that makes small objects nearer to the camera appear as large or larger than big things that are much further from the camera. But the example you posted is not a case of *forced perspective*.

Answer (score 0):

This type of effect would be achieved using post processing techniques.

To create the final image you would layer several individual photos on top of each other, using different blending modes and techniques. You can view these tutorials for more information regarding creating multilayered/montage images: http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2009/04/how-to-make-a-photoshop-montage/ and http://photoblogstop.com/photoshop/photoshop-blend-modes-explained

The resource images you would need would consist of your model on a plain background (usually studio white)
[image: Model on White background Example]

This will make it easier to cut your model out and transfer it to your montage/multilayered image.

For things like the large leafs and plants you collect various plant materials from a park or forest (an example) and then either photograph them on a white background [similar to the picture above] or scan them into your computer. Again this is done so that they can easily be cut out and transferred to your final image.

Finally you would need to take a picture of the background for your image. This could be taken anywhere.

You would then import all these different images into a program such as photoshop where you can blend them together to achieve the effect you desire!

Here is an example of a photo I did using a similar process: [image]

It's just a matter of playing around and experimenting with the image until you find the effect you were looking for!

[Please note the studio example image is not mine, I used it merely to illustrate an example. All rights belong to the original artist/author]